# Disable Spring-Cloud-Consul Health Indicator via properties

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-consul

Can you configure the property `management.health.consul.enabled` via a property source that is loaded after `bootstrap.yml`?.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: when you add that property to your application.properties or an equivalent property source, the value is not used. The only way I could get the consul health check disabled is by adding the property to bootstrap.yml

Answer (score -1):

See also [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/234). With Spring Boot 2.3.7.RELEASE I can enable/disable the Consul health indicator via property `management.health.consul.enabled` without any issues.

Comment: the issue linked just confirms the behaviour I was already seeing. The question was around being able to enable/disable the health check in the application.properties/yml. I also believe that this is still not possible due to the order at which the consul health indicator bean is configured.

Comment: So you still see this behavior? Then please add more details about your setup as it works with a recent Spring Boot version as I wrote.